# Como eu faço para adicionar um valor ao meu banco de dados?

Tags: c#, mysql

Preciso que, caso o valor seja nulo, ele adicionasse a variável `getid()` ao banco de dados.

```
string comando = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE username=@Usuario AND senha=@Senha AND tipo=1";
var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
var cmd = new MySqlCommand(comando, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", usuario);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Senha", senha);
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (leitor.Read())
{
    hd_id = leitor["id"].ToString();
}
if (hd_id == null)
{
    //Código aqui
}
int retorno = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Para que você está utilizando a variável retorno?

Comment: ela serve para retornar se a conexão foi feita certamente

Comment: getid() seria o id da inserção do usuário caso o usuário não seja encontrado no banco de dados?

Comment: Qual o problema? apesar que vejo alguns problemas no código? o que precisa fazer?

Comment: @AndrewPaes não, é um valor aleátorio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resgatar somente 1 valor, você não necessariamente precisa utilizar o reader, da para pegar direto do `ExecuteScalar();`. Para fazer a inserção do `getid()`, teria que fazer um update, da maneira que eu fiz, veja se lhe cabe bem.

O código, eu peguei o seu como base, apesar de não estar bem escrito.

```
string comando = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE username=@Usuario AND senha=@Senha AND tipo=1";
var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
var cmd = new MySqlCommand(comando, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", usuario);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Senha", senha);
connection.Open();
string id = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
if (id == "" || id == null)
{
    string update = "UPDATE usuarios SET id=@getid WHERE username=@Usuario";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(update, connection);
    string gid = getid();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getid", gid);
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```